# Select typedata set mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Please help, I'm new to MySQL. I'm wondering how I can write a query to produce the below result:

mytable

```
+----------+-----------+----------------+
| (int)id  | (set)code | (varchar)name  |
+----------+-----------+----------------+
| 1        |  1,2      | foo1           |
| 2        |  2        | foo2           |
| 3        |  4        | foo3           |
| 4        |  41,123   | foo4           |
+----------+-----------+----------------+
```

In column code is 'set' typedata that number is 'id' for join later to other table with (,) is separator

I want to result mytable for code = 2    // foo1 and foo2

So far I've tried the following, but haven't gotten it to return the data in the format I'm seeking:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where code = 2;     // foo2

select * 
from mytable 
where code like '%2%';    // foo1, foo2 and foo4
```

Thanks and any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Never, never, never store multiple values in a single column!!

Comment: Database Design Error. Google up a few basic Database Design Tutorials and then redesign your database

Comment: i know that insert any number on single row but i just want to know how if my table like that, thanks

Answer (score 2):

i got the answer

```
SELECT * from mytable where FIND_IN_SET('2',code);
```

Thanks all and really appreciated.